# Elasticsearch range with multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

This is the data i'm trying to query

```
    "price": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": 5,
          "c": 99,
          "d": 13,
          "f": 19
        }
```

My initial plan was to do something like this

```
    range: {
      "price.*": {
         gte: 10,
         lt: 15
       }
    }
```

Unfortunately it's not accepting field names with  wildcards

```
    multi_match: {
      query: "[10 TO 15]",
      fields: ["price.*]
    }
```

This is kind of working, works from 10 - 15, doesn't work from 1 to 15.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work from 1 to 15." ? Also instead of `multi_match` you need to use `query_string`